# Angular 7 Nested Lazy Loaded Children Routes

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular7-router

I have following code:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: './modules/user/user.module#UserModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'config',
    loadChildren: './modules/config/config.module#ConfigModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/user',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/user',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And App Router outlet as

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**config-routing.module.ts**

```
const configRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'lookups',
    loadChildren: './lookup/lookup.module#LookupModule',
    outlet: 'config',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: ConfigComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(configRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ConfigRoutingModule {

}
```

And Config Router outlet as

```
<router-outlet name="config></router-outlet>
```

**lookup-routing.module.ts**

```
const lookupRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id/options',
    component: LookupOptionComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LookupComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(lookupRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LookupRoutingModule {

}
```

Inside `ConfigComponent`, I am doing `this.router.navigate([`${path}`], {relativeTo: this.route});` where `path` is `lookups`.

The issue is whenever I route to `/config/lookups` or `/config/lookups/1/options` it redirects to `/config`. 
I see `NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/config/lookups", urlAfterRedirects: "/config"}` in the console and it's apparent that it's redirecting to config. I am not able to figure out why it is redirecting and cannot go to lookups component. 
I have looked into other issues here and no-avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the config routes like below. You need to add your child routes in your module under children array

const configRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ConfigComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children : [
         {
             path: 'lookups',
             loadChildren: './lookup/lookup.module#LookupModule',
             outlet: 'config',
             canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
         },
         {
              path: '**',
              redirectTo: '',
              pathMatch: 'full'
         }
    ]
  }  
];
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but it doesn't work. I doesn't even  load the `ConfigComponent`